# Permissions on ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions

I just installed Ubuntu and LAMPP. I am very new to all of this so bear with me. I've installed LAMPP to /opt/lampp

My /opt/lampp/htdocs folder is where http://localhost points at. For the past hour, I wasn't able to write in that directory. I finally did `sudo chown rondog /opt/lampp/htdocs` and now I cant write. (rondog is me, the only actual "user" on the machine)

When I run one of my PHP scripts, I get a permission denied error when I attempt to call an `fopen` method. What do I need to do so I am able to write to this folder as well as PHP can execute commands such as fopen and fwrite? Thank you

Comment: What group this directory [have][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771736/xampp-apache-alias-access-denied/5991461#5991461

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is setting the Apache user and group to `rondog`. This way, folders and files created can always be used by you and the server. It can be done as follows:

Edit (or create if it doesn't exist) `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and add the following lines:

```
User rondog
Group rondog
```

Save the file and restart the server:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Your newly added user should pop up whenever you use:

```
$ ps aux | grep apache
```

One advice though: keep your localhost files in your home directory. If you ever want a clean update of a new Ubuntu version, it's much easier to switch if you keep personal documents in your home directory. Furthermore, in that case you don't have to use the `sudo chown` command every time you create a new folder.

Comment: ah this worked for me..I first went through the finder window to open it but I could only get it read only, so I went through terminal, used sudo nano /path, edited and saved, restarted and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

You have several options here. Either you do what Tim H suggests:

```
chmod -R 777
```

This will set read and write permissions for everyone.

But usually this is too broad. You can instead create a new group, place yourself and the web server user inside it and allow only you two to access and write the files:

```
$ sudo -i
# addgroup lamppusers
# adduser rondog lamppusers
# adduser www-data lamppusers # check, that www-data is the correct user
# chown -R :lamppusers /opt/lampp/htdocs
# chmod g+srwx /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

If you're not sure, if `www-data` is the right LAMPP user, issue

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

and look for a line, that might look like being the user used by LAMPP. Otherwise, if you had the chmod 777 in place before, look at PHP-generated files with ls -l to see whom they belong.

The `g+srwx` is another way to write `777` access rights, but additionally sets the [sticky bit](http://google.com/search?q=sticky%20bit).

Finally, if you need more fine-grained access rights, google for File Access Control Lists (ACLs). They allow definitions of access rights on a per-user base.

Comment: ok so following what you laid out, I got to the www-data part and found that user using `cat /etc/passwd`. It points to `/var/www` which to me seems like it has no relation to the htdocs folder. I couldnt find any other user regarding lampp. Anyway, I followed this step by step and no luck, still getting a permission denied error. After all that, I stopped XAMP, logged out and back in, started it up and same error. I havent tried chmod -R 777, because I dont like the idea of compromising security

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
chmod -R 0777 /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

Comment: bad advice from a security standpoint